# Average values in a column by Class

Tags: excel, average, pivot-table

I need to create something that is used to track and report class ratings. The class evaluation form has eight questions and the ratings are from 1-4. We need to show the average rating for each question per class. It will be an ongoing list so needs to have functionality that allows users to continue to add new class ratings without re-formatting the spreadsheet.

Example, Class PD100 has a total of `5` for Q1.  I need to show the average score of `1.6` for that question.  Then the same for all the other questions grouped by Class.

```
Class # Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
PD100   1   2   3   1
PD100   3   2   3   4
PD100   1   2   3   1
PD200   2   1   2   2
PD200   1   2   3   4
PD200   1   4   1   4
PD300   1   4   4   1
```

Comment: Psst, you're looking for [pivot tables](http://superuser.com/q/405555/245923).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit unwieldy as the data is already laid out in a pivot, but the total average columns give you what you're looking for in creation of a pivot table.

if the data was laid out class question answer the pivot could be cleaner.

. 
    [image: enter code here]

Comment: That's exactly what I need!  Not sure why I made that so complicated.  Thank you.